# Mount external disk at the same mounting point in macOS

Tags: external-disk

I have an external disk, and I want to be mounted in the same mounting point (path) every time I connect.

In ubuntu I edited the file `/etc/fstab`, I added

```
UUID=5C2A-23AD /media/external1/    exfat        nofail,auto,noatime,rw,user 0 0
```

and is working. But I don't know how to do this in macOS 10.14.4

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, drives automount with the name that the drive provides to the OS (usually as soon as you plug it in/turn it on). For example, a drive named external1 will always mount to /Volumes/external1 on macOS, even if the /dev/disk[n] is different